# How to tell finder that my application is installed?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, osx-snow-leopard, automator

I am working on a cocoa application. I see a strange behaviour on Mac OS 10.6.8..!

My Cocoa application has an Automator action inside it. I want it to be listed in Automator as soon as I install it.

The conditions are as follows:
1. After installation, user should not go to the installed path.
2. User should not launch the application.

I mean, I am seeing this bug only for above mentioned situations. If I go to the installed folder, or launch the application, the automator app gets listed.

I didn't see this defect on Mac OS 10.7.5 or Mac OS 10.8.2..

Also I tried touch command via terminal just in case thinking that if any kind of Access updating is required and all. But that wasn't the case.

Any suggestions? Can I run any kind or Shell/Applescript while installing [After installation of the application] so that I can list the automator action in automator?

Any advice or help would be great!!

Comment: If its working in 10.7 and 10.8 but the issue is with 10.6. It may be worth your app checking the OS version and suggesting a Logout login after the install if it finds 10.6

Comment: Oh.. thank you for that suggestion. I've never tried it. But I wonder how good will it be to ask user to Log out /Restart after installing application?? Its not Windows OS ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a .txt file with the below script and then you have to add postflight script when taking .pkg file in Package Maker.

```
open "/Applications/yourAppName.app"
```

Comment: Can you please explain suresh??

Comment: What are u suggesting me??I don't want to launch my application when the installation is completed.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to achieve this please??

Answer (score 0):

Try this Terminal command.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister .../Whatever.app`

You shouldn't hard-code the path, though, as users sometimes stick apps in weird locations (citation: I do it :).